# Present new semi-transparent VC on top of view

Tags: ios, view, controller, storyboard, transparency

I've looked around and i can't seem to figure out this.

I'm simply trying to show a view on top of another one, but **from another VC**, and in **storyboard**.

The "idea" behinf this view is a kind of a pop-up/alert, and it'll eventually need a collection view and multiple buttons. So i figured i'd just do that with another VC since i need that "popup" in many places in the app.

Right now, i can do it, but my view is not transparent (even though my alpha is set correctly), so I'm guessing that the "under" view is actually gone and i've just made a regular "segue" using a different method. So i'm stuck.

And I cant just copy paste the whole VC class everywhere i need it so i can "addsubview" it...

Any idea?

This is what i'm doing :

```
AddFeelingViewController *adf = (AddFeelingViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddFeelingViewController"];

adf.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:adf animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The view appears and i can interact, but since it's very small i just need a "transparent background" which i haven't. Also, i'm planning to have a fullscreen button that removes the view. The classic "hit somewhere to cancel" type of button.

Any help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this project on Github, it has exactly what you need in "custom transition".

https://github.com/schneiderandre/popping

It was created using the Facebook pop animation engine.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need.
How can I add this to my project without using pods? I'm not sure what to import...

Comment: I used only the custom transition in my project, I imported: ManuallyViewController.h/m, DismissingAnimator.h/m, PresentingAnimator.h/m, and UIColor+CustomColors.h/m.. There is no need for pods. :)

Comment: Forget ManuallyViewController.h/m, its the ModalViewController. I changed the name and forgot to edit.

Comment: Hi again RJ, i've imported those files but i have #import issues, ofc i had an error asking for <POP.h>, so i important all the pop classes too, but now they generate import errors too. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: After importing the classes manually, the popping classes you named want me to import "POP.h" instead of <POP.h>, if i rename it, the POP classes generate errors. Maybe this is more clear ^^

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/pop this will show you how you need to add the library to your project.

Comment: I ended up using KLCPopup which is very similar so you definitly lead me in the right direction and also made me discover facebook POP. :) Here's an answer tag for you ! Thx man

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get alpha value but you could instead of presenting the viewController, you could simply add it to current view as subview along with alpha value as shown below :-

```
-(IBAction)newView:(id)sender {
  demoVc = (YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

  demoVc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
  [demoVc.view setAlpha:0.3];   //Set alpha value

   //    [self presentViewController:demoVc animated:YES completion:nil];

  [self.view addSubview:demoVc.view];
}
```

Also to remove you could simple create a IBAction method to remove it from superview.

Comment: This creates some problems too :
I don't need my whole view to be transparent, just the outer border where the user can tap to removeFromSuperview. Here everything is transparent, that can't be.
I tried reducing the size of the VC (and therefore the size of the view) to only the non-transparent part but it just fills the rest with blank and my main view is still hidden behind it

Comment: for transparency you could change the value of alpha value from 0.3 to 0.5. Also could u share a screen shot of what exactly u need it to be like as I'm not able to get it clear.